# How to fill dropdownlist for MVC4 razor views (C#)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

UserProfiles Model

```
[Table("Users")]
public class UserProfiles
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    //public string Password { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string TeamSub { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        **EDIT :** ViewBag.ProfileId = new SelectList(db.UserProfiles, "UserName", "UserName");
        return View(db.UserProfiles.ToList());
    }
```

In the View ( i hope / believe here is the issue )

```
@model IEnumerable<OilNGasWeb.Models.UserProfiles>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CLS - Oil & Gas Web Site Users";
}

<h2>Web Site Users</h2>


    **Removed** @Html.DropDownList(Model => Model.UserName,Model.UserName)
    **Changedinto** @Html.DropDownList("UserName", String.Empty)
```

New Error:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of 
type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'UserName'.
```

Comment: [Bind dropdownlist in mvc4 razor](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2013/06/bind-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a SelectList to your `ViewBag` in the Controller:

```
ViewBag.ProfileId = new SelectList(db.UserProfiles, "Id", "Username");
```

then add this in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProfileId", String.Empty)
```

*Moreover you should have used "model" instead of "Model" in your lambda expression.*

Comment: Thanks, but i was told not to use ViewBag for this, should I listen does it really matter?

Comment: after making your changes for some reason all my @.... Codes are underlines saying there not part of my project any idea?

Comment: seems to compile and run with the underlines , just wierd ... getting error System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Username'. with using your code

Comment: now i did change your code according to my model ... that should be correct? or not?

Comment: True, using ViewBags should be avoided most of the time, I only use them for dropdown lists in some cases, otherwise you can create a ViewModel

Comment: Be careful, I didn't use ViewData but ViewBag, they are different.

Comment: Oh i just copied the Error from the StackTrace in the Browswer, i did use ViewBag, not ViewData, not sure why its telling me something about ViewData, Sorry about the unclearity

Comment: Replace `ViewBag.ProfileId` by `ViewBag.UserName` in your case. The name of your ViewBag value must be the same as the one in your View.