# How to set relationship between two tables in mvc .net

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have just started to work with MVC and now i want to set relationship between two tables

**Here is my Employee table**

id | Name | Salary | Deptid

And here is my Deparrtment table

Deptid | Deptname

And now i have a create view to insert data into my Employee table

Like this

Name :..................
Salary :................
Deptid: a dropdown with list of departments [But when i save this in table it should save the corresponding deptid only]

And here you can see the models i have created

```
public class Employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int Deptid { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my other model Department

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int Deptid { get; set; }
    public string Deptname { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I have created one more class for Dbcontext

```
public class Employeecontext:DbContext<br>
{
    public DbSet<Employee>Employees{get;set;}
    public DbSet<Department>Departments{get;set;}
}
```

So as stated before I have a create view from where I will collect data and store them in the Employees table but one criteria is that in the dropdown I will have department names but I want to save the deptid of the corresponding department in table.

Thanks in advance and sorry if have not mentioned something or made any mistakes I am a newbie :P

Comment: Department table already have values manually entered by me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Salary { get; set; }
   public int Deptid { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Deptid")]
   public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
   [Key]
   public int Deptid { get; set; }
   public string Deptname { get; set; }
}
```

You don't have to include a list of employees in your department since it will only be dependent on the department.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following code for your entity classes. Your db-context class is OK. I've tested the below pattern in C# MVC4 applications without any issues with code-first approach.

```
public class Department
{

    public Department()
    {
        List<Employee>  EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Deptid { get; set; }
    public string Deptname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}


public class Employee
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int Deptid  { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Deptid ")]
    public virtual Department department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I changed my model to what you gave but when i click the submit button i get this error  The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Employees_dbo.Departments_Deptid". The conflict occurred in database "MELVIN", table "dbo.Departments", column 'Deptid'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Here is my controller code for the view create  [HttpGet]  
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
           ViewBag.dropdownlist = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Deptid", "Deptname");
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="id,Name,Salary,Deptid")] Employee emp)
        {
            db.Employees.Add(emp);
                db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }

Comment: ah. it may be because of the existing data or you may be trying to add values to fk field that do not available in main(department) table. You cant have values in fk field that are not available in main table(deptmnt). checkk that. code works perfect for me.

Comment: So i have a dropdownlist where i have list of departments from the table departments  but can't i just store the dept id of the departments in Employee table on selecting the department?

Comment: you can. But the dropdown can only have the ids available on department table. thats what FKs are. So then only the two tables can keep their relationship active

Comment: so in dropdown i must have Deptid instead of Deptname since deptid is the FK right ?

Comment: you can have both

<select id="Deptid" name="Deptid">
<option value=1>Dpt A</option> 
<option value=2>Dpt B</option> 
</select>

Comment: sorry for noob questions now you have hardcoded it but when retrieving from database how will you write the above code using html helpers

Comment: get a list of departments and put them in to the viewbag. then
display them using helpers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574290/how-to-fill-dropdownlist-for-mvc4-razor-views-c


     mark as answer if this is what you expected... :D

Comment: ViewBag.dropdownlist = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Deptid", "Deptname");                                 @Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist", "select")                    This is what i have done earlier

Comment: mark this as the answer if it works or post your own answer. so someone else can trust and use it in future.....